# Json not loading correctely in python

Tags: python, json

I am getting followers on Twitter using `Twython` library, it returns a json to me. But the issue is that the json contains single quoted string inside like `{"description":"i don't like this"}`, so when i dump to json and try saving to mysql i get an error saying there is an error in mysql query near \'. However, if i try to reduce the number of followers am getting which removes the part that has the quotes, i am able to save it to mysql correctly, but trying to retrieve it back and load it as json again, i get an error: Expecting ',' delimiter. if i use `json.dumps(eval(data))` i get error `invalid syntax` and if i try `json.loads(data)` i get `Expecting ',' delimiter`. below is a sample of my code

```
import json


def get_followers(self,count,cursor):
         result=None
         next_cursor=None
         if cursor=='' or cursor==0 or cursor=='0' or cursor==None:
            result=self.twitter.get_followers_list(count=count, screen_name=self.___twitter_handle___)
            next_cursor=self.get_next_cursor(result)
         else:
             result=self.twitter.get_followers_list(count=count, screen_name=self.___twitter_handle___,cursor=str(cursor))
             next_cursor=self.get_next_cursor(result)
         return result,next_cursor  



def get_next_cursor(self,the_json):
        next_cursor=None
        if 'next_cursor' in the_json and not the_json['next_cursor']==None:
            next_cursor=the_json['next_cursor']
        return next_cursor

data,next_cursor=user.get_followers(2,next_cursor)
            print('returned cursor ',next_cursor)

            print(type(data))

            #save the result in database
            if data:
                #Get the data already in the db
                query2="select id,data from twitter_data where id={0}".format(id)
                cur.execute(query2)
                rows=cur.fetchall();
                db_data=''
                new_data=[]
                for row in rows:
                    db_data=row[1]
                    if db_data==None or db_data=='':
                        new_data.append(data)
                    else:
                        db_data=json.dumps(eval(db_data))
                        db_data=json.loads(db_data)

                        #check if it is correctely parsed
                        for item in db_data:
                            print(item)
                        print('db_data ',type(db_data))
                        db_data.append(data)
                        new_data=db_data

                    #Save back the result in the database
                    new_data=json.dumps(new_data,separators=(',', ': '))
                    print(type(new_data))
                    query3="update twitter_data set data='{0}',next_cursor='{1}',crawler_status=1 where id={2}".format(new_data,next_cursor,id)
                    cur.execute(query3)
                    db.commit()
```

I am trying to implement the next cursor so each time i call the function it should get me the data already in db and load it as json in order to append the next one am getting to it, and that is where am having the problem.

Comment: If you already have a DB set up, why are you storing a list as a single JSON element? Create a new table and store the individual elements there. Then you won't have to read (and parse) all previous entries when you just want to add a new one.

Comment: The json am generating is continuation of the next page for the same person, just like pagination

Comment: Sure, but the paginated data is just a list of something (followers?), right? Break the list down into individual rows and insert them individually into a new table with a reference back to the rowid in `twitter_data` that they correspond to. That's the sort of thing databases are made for.

Comment: If you really want help with the current problem, we'll need to see some actual data you're having trouble with. If you're getting errors with `json.loads()`, odds are good you don't have valid JSON. Also get rid of the `db_data=json.dumps(eval(db_data))` line and show the full traceback of the error you get with the `json.loads()`.